# XQuery Nested For Loop

Tags: xml, for-loop, xquery

I've a sample xml file such as :

```
<user_manual document-type="IU" ts-cover="Language Part alt" ts-lang="-" ts-multi="Language Part, Chapter" ts-overview="-" metadata1="9211" brand="Bosch" material-number="dummy_9000727237" vib="RW404960" language-codes="de, en" production-date="2012-12-03" layout-type="-" id="SL9761901">
<embed-language_part id="SL14686180">
<language_part id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a14686169.SL9761756.7" role="-" lang="de">
<embed-user_manual_part id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a14686169.SL14686446.10">
<?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a17144756"?> 
<user_manual_part id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a17144756.SL9765760.11" role="-" document-type="IU">
<embed-chapter id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a17144756.SL9762101.13">
<?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a30660983"?> 
<chapter id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a30660983.SL2300626.14" role="-" toctitle="yes" footrowtitle="no" type="security">
<embed-title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a30660983.SL2361816.15">
<?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a611713"?> 
<title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a611713.SL873735.16" role="-">
<title id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a611713.SL873736.17">Sicherheits- und Warnhinweise</title> 
</title_module>
<?ecls-end-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a611713"?> 
</embed-title_module>
<embed-section id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a30660983.SL10400094.18">
<?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a11752692"?>  
<section id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a11752692.SL1742298.19" footrowtitle="no" role="-" toctitle="yes">
<?Pub Caret1?> 
<embed-title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a11752692.SL1742291.20">
<?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733"?> 
<title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733.SL984238.21" role="-">
<title id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733.SL984239.22">Bevor Sie das Gerat in Betrieb nehmen</title> 
<para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733.SL984240.23">Lesen Sie Gebrauchs- und Montageanleitung aufmerksam durch! Sie enthalten wichtige Informationen �ber Aufstellen, Gebrauch und Wartung des Ger�tes.</para> 
<para id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733.SL984241.24">Der Hersteller haftet nicht, wenn Sie die Hinweise und Warnungen der Gebrauchsanleitung missachten. Bewahren Sie alle Unterlagen f�r sp�teren Gebrauch oder f�r Nachbesitzer auf.</para> 
</title_module>
<?ecls-end-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733"?> 
</embed-title_module>
</section>
<?Pub *0000000275?> 
<?ecls-end-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a11752692"?> 
</embed-section>
</chapter>
</embed-chapter>
</user_manual_part>
</embed-user_manual_part>
</language_part>
</embed-language_part>
</user_manual>
```

I want to use the XQuery language but i am really new to this query language.

The infrastructure I need is this : I want to get the chapter's and its' sections with their titles, for example:

The chapter is like in this xml file :

```
    <chapter id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a30660983.SL2300626.14" role="-" toctitle="yes" footrowtitle="no" type="security">
    <embed-title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a30660983.SL2361816.15">
    <?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a611713"?> 
    <title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a611713.SL873735.16" role="-">
    <title id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a611713.SL873736.17">Sicherheits- und Warnhinweise</title>
...
```

In that example Sicherheits- ind Warnhinweise is the title of chapter element. Chapters can have many sections and in our example section's title is :

```
       <section id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a11752692.SL1742298.19" footrowtitle="no" role="-" toctitle="yes">
        <?Pub Caret1?> 
        <embed-title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a11752692.SL1742291.20">
        <?ecls-start-embedded-resource resource="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733"?> 
        <title_module id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733.SL984238.21" role="-">
        <title id="ecls_bio_becls_a3_a16181733.SL984239.22">Bevor Sie das Gerat in Betrieb nehmen</title> 
...
```

Bevor Sie das Gerat in Betrieb nehmen.

The expected structure :

```
<chapter> title:"Chapter's title"
<section>title:"First section's title"</section>
<section>title:"Second section's title"</section>
</chapter>
```

For that example chapter has just one section but I just configured this one to reach a solution of my file, it is most readable configuration I guess...

I tried below xquery query :

```
<chapter
    let $doc := doc("Test.xml")
    for $chapter in $doc/user_manual/embed-language_part/language_part/embed-user_manual_part/user_manual_part/embed-chapter/chapter
        let $chapter_title := $chapter/embed-title_module/title_module/title
        for $section in $chapter/embed-section/section
        return <chapter>title:{data($chapter_title)} <section> title:{data($section/embed-title_module/title_module/title)}</section></chapter>
```

with two nested loops, but this code makes my structure like :

```
<chapter>title:"Chapter's title"<section>"First section's title"</section></chapter>
<chapter>title:"Chapter's title"<section>"Second section's title"</section></chapter>
```

The problem was looping but when I try to edit code like this :

```
let $doc := doc("assemble.xml")
    for $chapter in $doc/user_manual/embed-language_part/language_part/embed-user_manual_part/user_manual_part/embed-chapter/chapter
        let $chapter_title := $chapter/embed-title_module/title_module/title
        <chapter> title:{data($chapter_title)} {
        for $section in $chapter/embed-section/section
        return <section> title:{data($section/embed-title_module/title_module/title)}</section>
        }</chapter>
```

I just want to put the  tag in the first loop ones, after that i will add section elements to query. But the above command is not working for my expectation.

So i need your suggestions to get these structure properly. Thank you in advance. I wish i was clearly told the situation to all of you. The name of file assumed as "assemble.xml".

Comment: I don't see anything in your query that *tries* to group by distinct values. Could you be more clear about what you want?

Comment: In general, you need to either use the XQuery 3.0 `group by` expression, or, if you're using an older version of the language, a `distinct-values()` filter.

Comment: ...but at the moment, I literally don't understand what you expect. Having such a huge document that it's hard to read doesn't help either -- if you could reproduce the issue with a 3-4 line XML file and comparably shortened code, that would be helpful, and in line with http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ...btw, http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#Group_By is a good reference for the XQuery 3.0 syntax, and there are *lots* of questions and answers already on StackOverflow showing the distinct-values() pattern for older versions of the language; one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745868/grouping-in-xquery

Comment: Sorry for the wrong explanations after editing post, i was about the finish working time and need to run to the shuttle so i forgot to edit the topic and my expectations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<chapters>{
let $doc := doc("assemble.xml")
for $chapter in $doc/user_manual/embed-language_part/language_part/embed-user_manual_part/user_manual_part/embed-chapter/chapter
return
    <chapter>
    title:{data($chapter/embed-title_module/title_module/title)}
        {
            for $section in $chapter/embed-section/section
                return <section>title: {data($section/embed-title_module/title_module/title)}</section>
        }
    </chapter>
}</chapters>
```

I searched around the internet and i found how to make inner loop operation. The code below is working perfectly for my expectations.

Comment: I don't see a group-by operation anywhere in this code (either using the direct XQuery 3.0 syntax or any effective workaround for lack of same in prior versions), making me still more curious about what your question actually meant.

Comment: Let me explain it like this, firstly i just though that as i will grouping the datas by their id's but after that i recognised that this is not a need for me, so i edit my question and after that i explained what i need actually. My first approach was wrong, if you read carefully after my edits you will see that i deleted the lines taking about grouping. I mentioned how i can control outer loop and inner loop together...