# Xquery nested hierarchy

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

I was trying to query for a XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<family>
    <person salary="1000">
        <name>Maria Fischer</name>
        <person salary="750">
            <name>Helmut Fischer</name>
            <person salary="830">
                <name>Maria Helbing</name>
                <person salary="0">
                    <name>David Helbing</name>
                </person>
            </person>
         </person>
    </person>
</family>
```

This is a hierarchy of persons in which a parent/child relationship in the XML document represents a parent/child relationship in the family. I want to query for the total sum of the salary of the whole family using XQUERY. I know somehow I have to use nested FLWOR return and fn:sum. I've tried

```
 for $p in doc("family.xml")/family
 return 
    for $p in $p/person
    return $p
```

I believe this can extract all the  node in XML. But I still don't know how to extract the salary attributes and sum them up. I'm pretty new to  XQUERY and haven't seen related questions on stackflow. [XQuery Nested For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482675/xquery-nested-for-loop) seems related but I still cannot figure it out. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You're all over-complicating it. It's simply

```
sum(//@salary)
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using xpath only:

```
//family/sum(.//person/@salary)
```

(tested on http://xpather.com/WVyWJ27N)

Using FLWR you can do it (as already suggested) very similarly: http://xpather.com/lUYxzXfC

Answer (score 0):

Nested FLWR expressions using selectors which use the `child::`-axis to descend the tree are never going to handle arbitrary recursion in the data.  Unless your `family` elements have fixed or maximum depth, you don't want nested FLWR expressions (at least, not for this reason).

Try a recursive function.  Or just something along the lines of

```
for $f in doc('family.xml')/family
return sum($f/descendant::person/@salary)
```

(not tested).